# Office 2016 and vb.net old projects compatibile

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, ms-office, excel-interop

I have around 2000 different dlls which are using Office Word/Excell for printing and making reports.

It works great on office 2003/7/10/13 but now when we upgraded it to office 2016 there is bunch of erros like

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass to interface type
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application

And on every project i got this error. I cant go through 2000 projects and change the reference. Is there any way for fixing this instead downgrading office.

Comment: "I have around 2000 different dlls" - wat? Why are these not consolidated?

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate. This issue is likely caused by your DLLs using the COM ProgID/GUIDs referring to an older version of Office which lingers on your system after an upgrade. You will need to rebuild all of your projects to update the references; perhaps use this as an opportunity to consolidate your projects. 2000 is excessive.

Comment: For 25 years they were developing those dlls